# In Python in what ways can u make an empty NumPy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-2.7

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakU9.jpg)

To make an empty Numpy the array

Comment: Please do not post links/images of code, post all code as formatted text in the question itself. Futhermore, what is your question exactly? The code you have posted does two completely different things

Comment: How do you intend to use this array?  Do not try to imitate a 'empty list' with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

If by *empty array*, you mean an array with 0 dimensions, you can simply convert to a NumPy array an empty list:

```py
import numpy as np

np.array([])
# array([], dtype=float64)
```

or use any of the NumPy's initialization functions with a `(0,)` or `0` shape, e.g.:

```
np.zeros((0,))
# array([], dtype=float64)

np.ones((0,))
# array([], dtype=float64)

np.empty((0,))
# array([], dtype=float64)

np.full((0,), 0.0)                                                                          
# array([], dtype=float64)
```

etc.

---

If by *empty* you mean an array of given size but not initialized (i.e. you only ask the OS for the required memory), you can use
[`np.empty()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) specifying the size you need, e.g.:

```
np.empty((2, 3))
# array([[1.46643506e-316, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000],
#        [0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000]])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways an empty NumPy array can be created: `numpy.zeros` and `numpy.empty`.

The syntax for using numpy.zeros and numpy.empty is shown below:

```
numpy.zeros(shape, dtype=float, order='C')
numpy.empty(shape, dtype=float, order='C')

# Shape -> Shape of the new array, e.g., (2, 3) or 2.

# dtype -> The desired data-type for the array,e.g., numpy.int8. Default is numpy.float64. This parameter is optional.

# order -> Indicates whether multi-dimensional data should be stored in row-major (C-style) or column-major (Fortran-style) order in memory. This parameter is optional.
```

how to use `numpy.zeros` to create an empty NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np
myArr = np.zeros((2,3))
print(myArr)
```

how to use `numpy.empty` to create an empty NumPy array:

```
import numpy as np
myArr = np.empty((2,3))
print(myArr)
```

`numpy.empty`, unlike `numpy.zeros`, does not set the array values to zero and, ​therefore, may be marginally faster. On the other hand, it requires the user to manually set all the values in the array ​and should be used with caution.